# Show google map markers from an array

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm having a problem with showing my markers. I successfully hide them in an array but I'm having problems on showing them back here is my code.

```
   function filtermark(){
 for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++ ) {
markersArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
    }
   function showmark(){
 for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++ ) {
markersArray[i].setMap(map);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Debug your code. `console.log(map)` to see what `map` is in the loop.

Comment: I declared `var map;` at the beginning of my js script. Before i primarily showed my markers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code you posted in your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020094/google-maps-api-clearing-markers), your map variable is local to your load function.  It probably needs to be global.

```
var map;
function load() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(...)
```